# I lost a css background image in the body tag using curl post

Tags: php, html, css, curl

I lost a css background image in the body tag using a curl post. It is set like this.

```
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(../Images/pattern4.png); // this one disappeared
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}
```

The Curl Post is.

```
$ch = curl_init();
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpStr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I was hoping that it would get solved automatically so I kept coding in another request using curl and I lost my ability to scroll the page on all pages also. The whole scroll bar on the right side of the page is gone. My code is a one class architecture and all Html is displayed using php.

Any Idea what the problem could be?

The site is www.bestspot2shop.com

I made two calls to an API that I made using curl to get info from a site and display it on my site. The first call lost me the background picture and the scrollbar on the side. Mouse over APITestPacks on the left side menu and click one the Medical, Tests link. Do you have any idea what the problem might be? I have an ssl certificate and sometimes that interferes with things.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the background image needs to be fully-qualified (http://) because it needs to point back to the original server.